# Confluence Proxy Error Reason : Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-12.04, confluence

Since this morning I have trouble accessing my confluence. It's on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

The error itself is this

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /xxx/xx/xxxxx.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

I use an apache with reverse proxy

my apache2 errorlog shows this :

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server

My apache config is this :

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.confluence.xxxxx.xxx
    ServerAlias confluence.xxxxx.xxx

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/ Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I saw some people fixing this by adding the Keepalive=On  but for me it didn't help.
I restarted apache2 of course.. no success.

Any Ideas? Let me know if you need more information, I can give all you need.

EDIT  :

I have to add that the official confluence page is offline or has troubles right now and when the problem started. Can that be related? I mean it's somehow connected, since you can install the updates and addons through interface.

EDIT 2 :

one of our users says that it crashed after he imported and xml document using the menue..

Comment: In addition to `Keepalive=On` can you try adding `ProxyPass..... Keepalive=On retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600` ?

Comment: I tried this as well, no success. I don't know how to restart the tomcat, since it came with confluence and i never used it for other purposes

Comment: i fixed it. the whole application crashed. and I had to restart all processes.